# Rails 4 - Devise not binding session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded my app to Rails 4. I have been authenticating the users with and only with a custom openid port over omniauth.

**Controller (Omniauth Callbacks)**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def openid
    @user = User.where(provider: auth_hash["provider"], uid: auth_hash["uid"]).first_or_initialize
    @user.name = auth_hash["information"]["name"]
    @user.email = auth_hash["information"]["email"]
    @user.save!
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  end

  protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end

root :to => "users#front"

[...]
```

**Issue**

After logging in correctly at the extern service, the user is being redirected back to `OmniauthCallback#openid`. The user is getting created correctly without any issues. After that the user is redirected to root without any problems. But at that point he is still not logged in!

My sessions are stored in the Database correctly aswell. I do not get any errors, it simply does not work as it should at `sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication`. How can I bind the session to the user properly?

**Update**

Using Cookies to store Sessions instead of the database doesn't solve.
Using `sign_in @user` and reloading page doesn't solve.
Using `@user.save` instead of `@user.save!` doesn't solve.

I'm grateful for any ideas.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue using omniauth-google-oauht2. Session goes through google and back into my app. It returns with the sign in successful flash, but if i do a check on `user_signed_in?` there is no user. 

Where you able to solve it?

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Any update on this? I am also seeing this issue, using Rails 4, devise, and omniauth-google-oauth2.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured something out. I added this line to my oauth callback method before "sign_in_and_redirect @user":

```
session[:user_id] = @user.id
```

After that, current_user is set properly. Hope this helps somebody.